# Under what circumstances is a class member function not passed self as the first parameter?

Tags: python

#### Problem

I am using a library to facilitate client side websocket communication with a server.

- The websocket library allows you to specify call back functions for when the socket opens, closes, errors or receives a message
- If I set my callback functions to be instance functions of another class, then they need to be passed the **self** parameter when the are called.
- I had understood that if you call a class instance method it will always be passed self as the first parameter. However,my callbacks are not getting  passed **self**

#### For example

```
from websocket import WebSocketApp
import websocket
class X(object):

    def run(self):
        self.ws  = WebSocketApp('wss://api.bitfinex.com/ws/2'
                            ,on_open=self.on_open
                            ,on_message=self.on_message
                            ,on_error=self.on_error
                            ,on_close=self.on_close)
        websocket.enableTrace(True)
        self.ws.run_forever()


    def on_open(self, ws):
        print('open')
    def on_close(self, ws):
        print('close')
    def on_message(self, ws, message):
        print('message')
    def on_error(self, ws, error):
        print('error')


if __name__=='__main__':
    x = X().run()
```

#### Output

```
error from callback <bound method X.on_open of <__main__.X object at 0x7fd7635e87f0>>: on_open() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ws'
  File "/home/arran/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_app.py", line 343, in _callback
callback(*args)
```

I am probably missing something basic here. But any help would be greatly appreciated

#### Edit

Looks like this might be a version specific issue with the websocket-client library https://github.com/home-assistant/home-assistant/issues/17532

I have downgraded to an earlier version and fixed my problem. 
I would still be curious to  know how this issue can arise though. My understanding was that class instance methods will always be passed **self** as the first parameter

Comment: `.on_open()` *is* being passed `self` - note that the error message is complaining about `ws`, the second parameter.  And that is due entirely to `WebSocketApp` not invoking that callback with a parameter.

Comment: what is the link to the pypi package you are using for websocket?

Comment: Ok, I see what you guys are saying. They have changed the interface. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to be an issue with the WebSocket class not passing the ws argument that your on_open method expects. I tried to reproduce it with my own dummy class, and it works fine.

```
class WS:
    def __init__(self, on_call):
        self.on_call = on_call
    def call(self):
        print("hi")
        self.on_call(self)


class X:
    def on_call(self, ws):
        print(ws)
    def run(self):
        self.ws = WS(self.on_call)
        self.ws.call()

X().run()
```

> ```
> hi
> <__main__.WS instance at 0x029AB698>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

> I am probably missing something basic here.

No, you were spot on. However, the `on_open` callback does not get called with the `ws` argument, although it should according to the documentation:

```
class WebSocketApp(object):
    (...)
        on_open: callable object which is called at opening websocket.
          this function has one argument. The argument is this class object.
    (...)
```

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client/issues/471) that was closed despite some discussion around the way it was fixed.

> would still be curious to know how this issue can arise though.

I guess it's an honest mistake in an attempted [bug fix](https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client/commit/efcf31b30122e05701fb3f696b029baf8faa6d8e). As there is no test for your particular scenario, it did not get caught.

[image]

> I have downgraded to an earlier version and fixed my problem

Please kindly submit a bug report or write a pull request to fix the problem.

> My understanding was that class instance methods will always be passed self as the first parameter

Yes, your understanding is correct. Here is an example mirroring what you tried.

```
class Server(object):
    def __init__(self, callback):
        self.callback = callback

    def run(self):
        self.callback(5)

class Client(object):
    def on_message(self, n):
        print("got", n)

client = Client()
server = Server(client.on_message)
server.run()
```